# React-Redux update specific element in store via its id

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi I have redux store as below:

```
{......"Device_Settings": [{
    "id": "1",
    "data": [{
        "ti": "IP Address",
        "v": "192.168.12.100",
        "d": "d",
        "m": "m",
        "t": "1",
        "i": "egauge-ip.info"
    }, {
        "ti": "Username",
        "v": "streambox",
        "d": "d",
        "m": "m",
        "t": "2",
        "i": "egauge-user.info"
    }, {
        "ti": "Password",
        "v": "streambox",
        "d": "d",
        "m": "m",
        "t": "2",
        "i": "egauge-pass.info"
    }, {
        "ti": "SPL number",
        "v": "",
        "d": "d",
        "m": "m",
        "t": "2",
        "i": "egauge-id.info"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "data": [{
        "ti": "IP Address",
        "v": "192.168.12.100",
        "d": "d",
        "m": "m",
        "t": "1",
        "i": "egauge-ip.info"
    }, {
        "ti": "Username",
        "v": "streambox",
        "d": "d",
        "m": "m",
        "t": "2",
        "i": "egauge-user.info"
    }, {
        "ti": "Password",
        "v": "streambox",
        "d": "d",
        "m": "m",
        "t": "2",
        "i": "egauge-pass.info"
    }, {
        "ti": "SPL number",
        "v": "",
        "d": "d",
        "m": "m",
        "t": "2",
        "i": "egauge-id.info"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "data": [{
        "ti": "IP Address",
        "v": "192.168.12.100",
        "d": "d",
        "m": "m",
        "t": "1",
        "i": "egauge-ip.info"
    }, {
        "ti": "Username",
        "v": "streambox",
        "d": "d",
        "m": "m",
        "t": "2",
        "i": "egauge-user.info"
    }, {
        "ti": "Password",
        "v": "streambox",
        "d": "d",
        "m": "m",
        "t": "2",
        "i": "egauge-pass.info"
    }, {
        "ti": "SPL number",
        "v": "",
        "d": "d",
        "m": "m",
        "t": "2",
        "i": "egauge-id.info"
    }]
}]}
```

I want to update each specific single element when user type in the input field. Some how the store update the same element for all the devices eventhough I used Object assign, manipulate the element via its id, update the clone object and dispatch. Would you spot out if I did anything wrong. Actually the store is quite big, it was updating good for none repeated element. When come to the repeated element, I couldnt update specific element via its id...my code update all the repeating element regardless of device id.

Here is my code below:

Component:

```
import Layoutstyles from "./Layoutstyles.css"
import $ from "jquery"
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import {Grid, Row, Col, Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem, Jumbotron, Button} from "react-bootstrap"
import { Fetch_SB_Current_Info, UpdateSBInfo, Fetch_Datacollector, save_device_info_value_to_globaldata } from "../actions/StreamboxActions"
@connect((store) => {
  return {
    streamboxdata:store.streamboxdatastore.streamboxdata,
  };
})

export default class DeviceInputvalue extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super();
    this.handleChangeDeviceInput = this.handleChangeDeviceInput.bind(this);
    this.alertValue = this.alertValue.bind(this);
    this.savevaluetomodel = this.savevaluetomodel.bind(this);
    this.state = {value:null};
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    const where = this.props.where;
    this.setState({value: where.v});
  }
  handleChangeDeviceInput(evt) {
    console.log("I'm Clicked from deviceid " +this.props.deviceid);
    this.setState({value: evt.target.value});
    console.log("value from device id "+this.props.deviceid + " from dc type "+ this.props.dcname +" from row "+this.props.where.ti);
    var newvalue = Object.assign({},this.props.where);
    newvalue.v = evt.target.value;
    console.log(newvalue);
    this.savevaluetomodel(newvalue,this.props.streamboxdata,this.props.where.ti,this.props.dcname,this.props.deviceid);
  }
  alertValue() {
  }
  savevaluetomodel(value,model,where,dcname,deviceid){
    this.props.dispatch(save_device_info_value_to_globaldata(value,model,where,dcname,deviceid));
  }
  _displayHelp(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.streamboxdata));
  }
  render() {
    const where = this.props.where;
    const deviceid = this.props.deviceid;
    console.log(deviceid);
    return(
        <Grid fluid={false}>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={4} md={4} lg={4}>
              <label>{where.ti}</label>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={4} md={4} lg={4}>
              <input className={Layoutstyles.fullwidth} value={this.state.value} type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeDeviceInput}></input>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={4} md={4} lg={4}>
              <button className={Layoutstyles.buttonHelp} onClick={this._displayHelp.bind(this)}>Help</button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my action:

```
export function save_device_info_value_to_globaldata(valueobject,globaldata,where,dcname,deviceid){
  // console.log(value);
  // console.log(globaldata);
  // console.log(where);
  // console.log(dcname);
  // console.log(deviceid);
  return function (dispatch){
    var newcopy = Object.assign({},globaldata);
    for (var i = 0; i < newcopy.Monitored_Devices.length; i++) {
      var devicetype = newcopy.Monitored_Devices[i];
      console.log(devicetype);
      if (devicetype.Title==dcname){
        console.log(devicetype);
        for (var k = 0; k < devicetype.Device_Settings.length; k++) {
          var eachdevice = devicetype.Device_Settings[k];
          if (eachdevice.id==deviceid){
            console.log(eachdevice.id);
            for (var m = 0; m < eachdevice.data.length; m++) {
              if (eachdevice.data[m].ti == valueobject.ti){
                eachdevice.data[m].v = valueobject.v;
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    dispatch({type:"FETCH_SBINFO_FULFILLED", payload: newcopy})
  }
}
```

Here is my reducer

```
export default function reducer(state={
    streamboxdata:[],
    // datacollector:[],
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    posting: false,
    posted: false,
    error: null,
  }, action) {

    if (typeof(action.payload)!=='undefined'){
      // console.log(action.payload.SBInfo);
    }

    switch (action.type) {
      case "FETCH_SBINFO_REJECTED": {
        return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
      }
      case "FETCH_SBINFO_FULFILLED": {
        // console.log(state);
        // console.log(streamboxdata);
        return {
          ...state,
          fetching: false,
          fetched: true,
          streamboxdata: action.payload,
        }
      }

      case"FETCH_SBINFO_FULFILLED_DETECT":{
        console.log(action.payload);
      }

      case "POST_SBINFO_REJECTED":{
        return {...state, posting: false, error: action.payload}
      }

      case "POST_SBINFO_FULFILLED":{
        return {
          ...state,
          posting:false,
          posted:true
        }
      }
      // case "Fetch_Datacollector_Fulfilled":{
      //   return {
      //     ...state,
      //     fetching:false,
      //     fetched:true,
      //     datacollector: action.payload,
      //   }
      // }
    }

    // console.log(state);
    return state
}
```